# Why is PaneSelector caching nested Dynamics and how to switch it off?

Tags: bugs, front-end, dynamic, gui-construction, scheduling

**Bug introduced in V10.4 or earlier and persisting through V11.3**

> CASE:3875733, confirmed

---

It seems that `Dynamic` content is somehow cached by `PaneSelector/FrontEnd`.

Even weirder, it does respond to evaluation though it uses old values, incorrectly.

Here is a minimal example:

```
  (*our panel, Dynamic + := may seem strange but remember this is only an example*)
paneContent[] := Dynamic[Print[1]; DateString[]]

  (*our app implementation with PaneSelector*)
DynamicModule[{pane},
 Panel @ Column[{
    Button["test", pane = "pane"],
    Button["init", pane = "init"],
    PaneSelector[{
      "default" -> "default",
      "pane" -> Dynamic[pane; Print["pane"]; paneContent[]]
      }
     , Dynamic[ pane ], ImageSize -> {200, 50}

     ]

    }]
 ]

   (*same functionality implemented with Dynamic only*)

DynamicModule[{pane = "init"},
 Panel@Column[{
    Button["test", pane = paneContent[]],
    Button["init", pane = "init"],
    Pane[Dynamic[Print["pane"]; pane], {200, 50}]

    }]
 ]
```

Now toggle between  test and init and observe what happens.

The second panel updates date while the first show only the initial one. Even though the `Print[]` statement is evaluated! I don't understand this at all, it seems that FrontEnd caches `paneContent[]` somehow.

Can I prevent that?

Comment: `paneContent[]:=Dynamic[pane;Print[Stack[_]];DateString[]]` with `"pane" -> paneContent[]` seems working. So it looks like the `Dynamic` in `paneContent[]` needs to be triggered explicitly. But I don't understand what is the relation between the global `pane` and the localized `pane`.

Comment: @Silvia `paneContent` is independent from `DynamicModule` so can't use it. The more that bare `Dynamic` works, I just won't use `PaneSelector`. For me it is just crazy that this prints `Print["pane"]; paneContent[]` but it doesn't evaluate `paneContent[]`. I suppose it is a side effect of something which should have made our lifes easier, again. Thanks for your attention :)\

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Edit

Using knowledge from [Dynamic triggered but renders the same content](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/166011/5478) we can enhance our `Dynamic` to always re-render:

```
...
"pane" -> Dynamic @ DynamicModule[{$flag = RandomReal[]}
, pane; Print["pane"]; paneContent[]
]
...
```

This way `Dynamic` will always see different `$flag` and re-render.

#### Old answer

The bug (not documented optimization which is a pain for those who are not aware of it) is confirmed so before it is fixed we need to use something which will mimic `PaneSelector` instead. So simply `Dynamic + Switch`.

```
paneContent[] := Dynamic[ DateString[]]

DynamicModule[
    {pane = "init"}
  , Panel @ Column[{
        Button["test", pane = "pane"]
      , Button["init", pane = "init"]
      , Dynamic[
            Switch[pane, "init", "init", "pane", paneContent[]]
          , TrackedSymbols :> {pane}
        ] 
    }]
]
```

This slightly differs from the example in a question as `paneContent` isn't evaluated each time you click "text" button but only when `pane's` value changes. This way it is closer to what `PaneSelector` does.