# What is the point of PaneSelector?

Tags: performance-tuning, front-end, gui-construction

### Intro

`PaneSelector` looks like a pretty idiomatic way to toggle displayed content e.g.:

```
PaneSelector[
  {True -> progressBar, False -> button}
, Dynamic @ processing
]
```

Analogous `If` version:

```
Dynamic[ If[processing, progressBar, button] ]
```

The difference is that `PaneSelector` content will be converted to boxes and each switch can be faster than `Dynamic` which contents are sent for typesetting every time it is refreshed. Shortly, for `PS` only the value of `processing` does the round trip while for `Dynamic[If[...]]`, full content.

**Sounds good, does not work. I regret each time I use it.**

### Problem 1

```
DynamicModule[{processing = False, longProcedure},
 longProcedure[] := Pause[2];
 With[{
   progressBar = ProgressIndicator[Appearance -> "Indeterminate"],
   button = Button["Run", processing = True; longProcedure[];         processing = False, Method -> "Queued"],
   buttonAsync = Button["Run async", processing = True;         RunScheduledTask[longProcedure[], {.1}, "EpilogFunction" :> (processing = False)], Method -> "Queued"]
   },
  Grid[{
    {"processing:", Style[Dynamic @ {processing}, Bold], SpanFromLeft},
    {"PS:", PaneSelector[{True -> progressBar, False -> button},           Dynamic@processing, ImageSize -> All]},
    {"If:", Dynamic[If[TrueQ@processing, progressBar, button]]},
    {},
    {"PS:", PaneSelector[{True -> progressBar, False -> buttonAsync},           Dynamic@processing, ImageSize -> All]},
    {"If:", Dynamic[If[TrueQ@processing, progressBar, buttonAsync]]},
    {},
    {"Just toggle:",  Button["toggle", processing = ! processing;, Method -> "Queued"]},
    {"Toggle and pause:", Button["toggle2", processing = ! processing; Pause[2];,  Method -> "Queued"]}
    }, Alignment -> Left]
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

- Pressing `Run` affects only `If` based solutions and not `PS`.
- Pressing `Run async` shows both progress bars but when it is done only the `If` based solution shows the button back.
- `Simple toggle` works as expected
- `Toggle and pause` triggers `PS` based solution only after `Pause` is finished.

Using `FinishDynamic` is an overkill here.

### Problem 2

It does undocumented caching so you need to inject to your view stuff like random numbers:

[Dynamic triggered but renders the same content](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/166011/5478)

[Why is PaneSelector caching nested Dynamics and how to switch it off?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140739/5478)

Do you fancy debugging by inserting `RandomReal[]` here and there? I do not.

### Problem 3

Since it usually has `PaneSelector[{__}, Dynamic[_Symbol]]` form, you don't know when this [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) will hit you:

[What is the difference between Dynamic[x] and Dynamic[ h[x] ] for DynamicModule variables?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100828/5478)

### Question

Did I miss the point of this function? What are the basic rules to follow to not face problems like this? Or is it better to just ignore this function which is what I would suggest to do.

Comment: [cross posted in community.wolfram.com](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1345239)

Comment: "Sounds good, does not work. I regret each time I use it." QFT. That's all.

Comment: There's a known bug about the FE doing some overzealous optimisation so the PS versions can be made to work with adding a +0 to the Dynamic, ie `PaneSelector[{True -> progressBar, False -> button}, Dynamic[processing+0], ImageSize -> All]`

Comment: @Gerli You probably mean Problem3, nice trick! I was usually using `Dynamic[ First @  {processing}]` but this does not help here while your `+0` does. :D How ridiculous is this discussion now? XD

Comment: @Kuba yes, that looks like a Problem3. But that is also what will make the PS examples work in Problem1

Comment: The real problem seems to be that someone thought undocumented "optimizations" in the FE would be a good idea. After years of using and programming CDF apps (and I still have to maintain a few) I come to the conclusion that the whole Dynamic design is flawed and it probably is quite unfixable (for any really serious non-trivial application).