# 'Visibility' of Dynamics in TabView with respect to SynchronousUpdating

Tags: bugs, evaluation, gui-construction, scheduling

**Bug introduced in 11 or earlier and persisting through 12.0.0**

> CASE:4076464

---

#### Example 1

```
TabView[
 {
  "off",
  Dynamic[Print@RandomReal[]; "on", UpdateInterval -> .5, SynchronousUpdating -> False]
 },
 ImageSize -> Automatic
]
```

Once you switch to pane `2` it will not stop priniting even if you go back to `1`. It does not happen when `SynchronousUpdating` is `True`.

#### Example 2

```
Column[{
  PopupMenu[Dynamic[n], {1, 2}],
  TabView[
   {1 -> Dynamic[Echo[{1, Now}]; n, SynchronousUpdating -> False ],
    2 -> Dynamic[Echo[{2, Now}]; 2 n , SynchronousUpdating -> False]
    },
   ImageSize -> Automatic
   ]
  }
 ]
```

I expect each Dynamic to evaluate only when is visible, that is why `ImageSize->Automatic` is there.

The very first time it works well. But then, when `n` is changed with `PopupMenu`, which should refresh currently visible tab, all previously visited tabs are refreshed...

[image]

If `SynchronousUpdating -> False` is `True` everything is as expected:

[image]

While I don't insist on any behavior, they should at least be consistent.

Have I missed anything?

#### Related topics

Together with other 'issues' it makes controlling `TabView/PaneSelector/MenuView` and friends really painful:

[Why is PaneSelector caching nested Dynamics and how to switch it off?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140739/5478)

[What is the point of PaneSelector?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/173940/5478)

Comment: So if your app runs slowly even though you took care about wrapping stuff with `Dynamic` to delay refreshing etc, now you know.

Comment: Try with `Print` instead of `Echo`.  I think this is the difference between `Echo` returning the expression and `Print` not doing so.  However, notice that all tabs that are selected between a`PopupMenu` selection are marked for update.  You can see this clearer by adding a third tab, updating `PopupMenu` select, another tab, select the original tab, then update `PopupMenu`.

Comment: @Edmund I don't see any difference with Print, except of where it is printed. And yes, I know, I said "all previously visited tabs are refreshed".

Comment: When I use `Print` instead of `Echo` then only the visible tab prints.  I am on 11.3. What version are you on?

Comment: @Edmund V11.3 on Win10.